# Getting the parent delimiters via RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get the parent delimiters in a string below using RegEx match colletion.;

```
string value = "{line 1 {subline}$}{line 2}{line 3}";
```

So far here is my code;

```
 string value = "{line 1 {subline}$}{line 2}{line 3}";
 var reg = new Regex(@"\{(.+?)\}");
 MatchCollection properties = reg.Matches(value);
```

and I am getting this;

```
{{line 1 {subline}}
{{line 2}}
{{line 3}}
```

But my expected result must be;

```
{{line 1 {subline}$}}
{{line 2}}
{{line 3}}
```

Anyone know how to ignore the child field from the string? Thank you!

Comment: Your *brackets* don't match, which in-turn is causing my *OCD* to fire off about *degrees of freedom* and all the ways this would break

Comment: Oh i see you have fixed it sneakily... Which raises even more questions, why would you expect this `{{line 2}}` ? note that the regex pattern you supplied wouldnt output that anyway

Comment: Yeah. Sorry about that.

Comment: {{line 2}} & {{line 3}} i need these because I am mapping them to some values.

Comment: So you want to put brackets around matches that only have one set of containing bracket ?

Comment: I want the {subline} to be included in {{line 1}} like; {{line 1 {subline}$}} but I really don't know how to write regex for this.

Comment: As I understand you only want the first level of brackets, not the further nested ones. But regex seems not ideal to do that.

Comment: You are right @XouDo. But with the given code below, the requirement has been met. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this O(n) without regex.

**Given**

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetTokens(string input)
{
   var count = 0;
   var pos = -1;
   for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
   {
      if (input[i] == '{') count++;
      if (input[i] == '}') count--;
      if (count == 1 && pos == -1) pos = i;
      if (count != 0 || pos == -1) continue;
      yield return '{' + input[pos..(i + 1)] + '}';  // this would allocate less without the brackets
      pos = -1;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
string value = "{line 1 {subline}$}{line 2}{line 3}";

foreach (var token in GetTokens(value))
   Console.WriteLine(token);
```

**Output**

```
{{line 1 {subline}$}}
{{line 2}}
{{line 3}}
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3AoLcg)

<sub>***Note** : The only reason for this answer is because I wanted to use a range (don't judge me)*</sub>

Comment: This is a very pretty solution. BIG THANKS!

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again. With the given string value, the code is working fine, but whenever there are new string values, it will throw an exception about its startIndex parameter. 
I tested this string...
```
string value = ""{LINE}-sometexthere, {LINE2}, {LINE3}. some text here.""
```
Then this exception will be thrown;
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'StartIndex cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'startIndex')'